# how to implement application load balancer for the tomcat host.. where the weburl is not changing

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

Need some help with Application load balancer. In my company they ask me implement application load balancer on test env. where we have 2 EC2 Instance, Instance 1 and Instance 2. Instance 1 has 1 tomcat instance running and the other EC2 instance has 4 tomcat instance running.

how can i configure the application load balancer on this. as i was looking in to it.. the web url for our application doesn't change to implement path base routing.

any help would be really apprecaite.

Thanks for replying...........

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are looking for information on how the routing needs to be done from a single web url to 2 EC2 instances (1 Instance having 1 Tomcat and second instance having 3 tomcats).

To achieve this, you can use an application load balancer with

- 1 listener with whatever web url/path you prefer.
- In step 5 of load balancer configuration (Register Targets), add 4 entries totally. This should be like :

  ```
     - Instance 1 Private IP and port of single tomcat instance
     - Instance 2 Private IP and port of first tomcat instance in that instance
     - Instance 2 Private IP and port of second tomcat instance in that instance
     - Instance 2 Private IP and port of second tomcat instance in that instance
  ```

Hope this helps. Do reply in case you need further info on each step.